# Would introducing outlier removal potentially stop my transformer model from learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have recently added in Z-score outlier removal to the preprocessing for my transformer model and now the model is learning basically at all. It was working before Introduced this Would have adding this meant caused that or is it more likely that I have introduced that i have not yet been able to find?

[Before outlier removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgaHo.png)

[After outlier removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZRxi.png)

I have tried to find a bug by unit testing and looking at the observed outputs of different parts of the pre processing but it all looks okay. what am I missing?

apologies in advance if this is a stupid question I am very new to Neural networks

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial to know what data you are exactly working on.
Outlier removal comes into picture when we have numerical data. Transformer models will be used in parlance of Vision and NLP.

The preprocessing steps which are followed in that case are different than the   regular classification and regression tasks.

These include :

1. Tokenization
2. Vocabulary mapping
3. Padding&Truncation
4. Normalization

This is when the text data comes into picture. As far as transformer models are concerned, many of these tasks are integrated inside the models and hence we need not manually do them.
It is like a plug and play model.

Hence, the model selection in the first place needs to be evaluated for the matter. It would hence be difficult to find out any correlation between outlier removal and its effect on transformer model as they belong to different subjects.